# error in converting String to Calendar?

Tags: java, eclipse, calendar, simpledateformat, parseexception

i want to get arrival date of a client in string and pass it as a parameter to strToCal method,this method returns an Calendar object with that date,but it wouldn't work,id get parse exception error:

```
static String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
System.out.println("enter arrival date ("+ pattern +"):\n" );
c.setArrDate(strToCal(sc.next(),c));
System.out.println("enter departure date ("+ pattern +"):\n");
c.setResTilDate(strToCal(sc.next(),c));

static Calendar strToCal(String s, Client c) throws ParseException {
    try{
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(df.parse(s));
        return cal;
    } catch(ParseException e){
        System.out.println("somethings wrong");
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what's the type of c and what's the implementation of Client?

Comment: can you log your exception and add it to your post?

Comment: c is an object of client object,                                  public class Client extends Person implements Serializable {
 Client(){
  this.payBill=0;
 }
 private String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
 private long payBill;
 private Room room;
 private Calendar arrDate,resTilDate;
  @almasshaikh

Comment: this code should work as long as you provide the correct input string. the strings must respect your pattern. so enter dates as 2014-05-16 13:30:00. the problem is sc.next(), you need sc.nextLine(), because sc.next() will split on the first space

Comment: @MihaiC but it doesn't

Comment: @shayan check and try answer

Comment: @shayan Please add code into question. Paste whole client class not just first few lines.

Comment: Print the String before conversion, will let you know whether actual date is available or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `sc.next()` with `sc.nextLine();`

because `sc.next()` will split on the first space and your input string won't be of the correct pattern.

**Edit** I've tried this code:

```
public class Test4 {
    static String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("input date: ");
        String a = input.nextLine();
        c = strToCal(a);
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
    }


    static Calendar strToCal(String s) {
        try {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(df.parse(s));
            return cal;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

with `next()`:

```
input date:
2014-05-16 13:30:00
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-05-16"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
```

with `nextLine()`:

```
input date:
2014-05-16 13:30:00
Fri May 16 13:30:00 EEST 2014
```

Comment: that doesn't work either,when i put nextLine() instead of next() it won't get the input and prints the parse exception error

Comment: i've posted entire example code. It works with nextLine(). Are you using nextInt() somewhere before this? If so, create two different scanners, one for int and one for strings. nextLine() doesn't work correctly if you invoke nextInt() before